# Are caches reconfigured after they are created by Code or other nodes?

Tags: java, ignite

Ignite seems amazing cool; hoping to start using it to replace some middleware components that we are still using and still trying to learn everything.

Read a lot of docs and books, but still had a hopefully simple question ; what happens if there is already a cache defined in the cluster and then either in config of a new node, or in Java code it attempts to get created again but with a different configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration of existing cache (with the same name) will be used and new configuration of joining node will be discarded (provided you do that with `getOrCreateCache()`).

Most of cache settings cannot be changed once cache is created.